# how to download very large files in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, browser-cache

On Windows 7 running Chrome browser, downloading a 3.2TB file to a USB drive say `F:\big-files\` with 3.5TB free fails because "Disk Full". It appears that Chrome uses a temporary folder for downloads which would be on `C:\somewhere` (`%appdata%\whatever`) which has nowhere near enough space.

Research suggests adding `--disk-cache-dir="F:\big-cache"` to the program shortcut.

My question is (without downloading for days to find out): will Chrome successfully move the file from `F:\big-cache\` to `F:\big-files\` when the file occupies 90% of the space available on the drive?

I think it will work because the move just needs to change the file pointer and not physically move the file, but if that's wrong, how to successfully download the file?

Should I just set my cache to `F:\big-files` so the cache is the destination and be done with it, or is that also doomed for some reason?

**Update**

Under `F:\big-files\` there is a new directory structure `Default\` which contains `Default\Cache` and `Default\Code Cache`. I assume it was created by Chrome. If so why has the download failed? Surely I don't need double the space to download any given file?

Comment: You may want to use a download manager instead of chrome in this case. I suggest jdownloader

Comment: @mashuptwice not sure I can use a download manager, it seems extensions can no longer be installed on offline systems but will keep investigating

Comment: A download manager is not (necessarily) an extension.

Comment: I very much doubt Chrome downloads to its cache folder or any other folder but the download folder. Doing so would be prohibitively slow.

Comment: @DanielB At least on Linux with Chromium I can definitely say that it does. Note that for moving a file on the same drive it doesn't need to be copied to a different physical block on the storage device, only the index needs to be updated with the new location.

Comment: @gloopy as others pointed out, a download manager can be a standalone program. The advantages over downloading with a browser are that most write directly to the specified location, as well as allow you to cancel a download and restart it without loosing progress. You might want to elaborate what you mean by "offline systems"

Comment: @mashuptwice Well yes, but also no. Chrome only does that when its temp folder and the download target are on the same filesystem. Because only than can it _rename_ the file, yes. // So instead, this sounds like something worth reporting once the exact behavior is nailed down (with a smaller file and a similarly limited amount of space, if possible).

Comment: @DanielB Your statement is incorrect, I've just tested it in a Windows 10 VM with a second drive attached. The file still gets downloaded to a temporary folder on the C: drive until it is complete. Meanwhile on the second drive the drive is only 32kB in size.

Comment: My statement is 100% correct. You can verify it yourself using Task Manager and a USB flash drive or the like. No data is written to C: during the download. The apparent file size as displayed in Explorer is not an indicator of actual disk space consumed until all programs have closed a file.

Comment: To clarify, by offline I mean no internet access. Programs or extensions have to be downloaded and then manually transferred into the environment. The environment is also heavily locked down and although I am a privileged user the vibe is "install as little as possible".

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution of adding `--disk-cache-dir=D:\location` won't work. I've tested it with a 1GB file, the folder would not grow past 6MB in size. It seems chrome uses another folder as temporary download directory.

Others stated that chrome would download the file to its final directory if this is on a different drive, I could not reproduce that behavior as seen in the screenshot

[image: chrome download]

Fortunately there are other solutions which work out of the box:

### Using a download manager

Download manager are specifically made for downloading many and large files.
A download manager like [JDownloader](https://jdownloader.org/) has various advantages in comparison to downloading via a browser:

1. stopping and resuming the download without loosing data
2. limiting the download bandwidth
3. downloads to the specified location instead of a temporary folder

And many more which are not critical to your usecase.

### Use Firefox

[Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) will download the file directly to the specified location as a `<originalfile>.<extension>.part` file and rename it to `<originalfile>.<extension>` after completion.

Comment: I see the benefit of a download manager. Chrome was selected for the environment and while I prefer Firefox I'm not inclined to install it unless I run out of options. Currently I am running `disk-cache-dir="F:\destination"` and have set the download destination the same. So far so good, nearly 650GB downloaded to a file named `Unconfirmed<numbers>.crdownload` with no impact to C:\ (100Mbps network, 5 day download). At this point it looks like the download will complete OK and the file will be renamed, and that's all I need.

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution worked for me.

1. Append `disk-cache-dir="F:\destination"` to the target field of the Chrome shortcut
2. Start Chrome
3. Under Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Downloads enable "Ask where to save each file before downloading"
4. Begin the download of `<some-enormous-file>`
5. When prompted for the file destination select `F:\destination`
6. In case you don't believe it's working, check progress on the Chrome Downloads tab `Ctrl-J` and/or refresh Windows Explorer and watch as `F:\destination\Unconfirmed <numbers>.crdownload` increments in size. Watch with pleasure as the download size in either view exceeds the disk space on C:\ and continues
7. Wait longer.

More permanently the download location can be set to `F:\destination` and the location prompt turned off . I did not do this because I was downloading two files and F:\ is removable in my case.